# Macbook Air (mid 2013) daisy chaining two Dell U2715H?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport

I have a Macbook Air (mid 2013) and two Dell U2715H monitors.

I am able to connect the one monitor to the Macbook via the DisplayPort-MiniDisplayPort cable. This works great!

Now I want to connect the second monitor. This I can do via the DP1.2 (out) port on the first monitor and then attach it to the MiniDisplayPort in the second. Also works... well, not so great. It just mirrors the first screen.

Is there anyway to tell the Mac (Yosemite) that it's actually two monitors? Both the monitors and the Macbook Air seems to support DP1.2 and MST.

I have read various posts here on StackExchange and other sites, that states that this should both be possible and that it is impossible, so I'm a bit in the dark here.

One of the posts mentioned that it was a driver issue, and that it worked OK on Windows 7 and 8.

Are there any software or third party driver that would make it work?

Comment: You cannot daisy-chain display port, only Thunderbolt.

Comment: @Tetsujin: That's not true. Have a look here: http://www.displayport.org/cables/driving-multiple-displays-from-a-single-displayport-output/ You can with DP1.2 and MST, which, as I write, both monitors and the Macbook Air seems to support.

Comment: The Macbook has an Intel HD Graphics 5000, which is said to support DP1.2 here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-reference-guide-to-intel-processor-graphics

Comment: The monitors have a setting to enable DP1.2

Comment: …but the Mac doesn't. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204154

Comment: I'm not sure what you are hinting at with that link? Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: 3. Can I connect my Mini DisplayPort monitor or monitor using a Mini DisplayPort adapter to my Apple Thunderbolt Display?
Mini DisplayPort Monitors or Monitors connecting with Mini DisplayPort adapters will not function when connected through a Thunderbolt Display. They must be connected directly to the Thunderbolt port on the computer or to a non-display device as indicated above.

Comment: But, I'm not trying to connect a Mini DisplayPort to an Apple Thunderbolt Display. I'm trying to utilize the MST protocol via DP1.2, but I think this is a lost cause. I'll just have to uninstall OS X and use Windows or Linux instead, as these do support this protocol with these monitors.

Comment: correct, Mac doesn't use MST.